# OnClickListener on the Listview Filter

Tags: android, listview

How can i put an onclicklistner on the specified row that the user searched on the searchView. ive been trying to figure out how to but when i do it it always shows the first row's toast or Uri link. Can anyone help me??

like for example when I search ABC i want to click it to see a toast or a Uri link when i click on it.

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {

private String name;
private int age;

public  Employee(String name,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public int getAge(){
    return age;
}}
```

**EmployeeAdapter.java**

```
public class EmployeeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

public Context context;
public ArrayList<Employee> employeeArrayList;
public ArrayList<Employee> orig;

public EmployeeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Employee> employeeArrayList) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.employeeArrayList = employeeArrayList;
}


public class EmployeeHolder
{
    TextView name;
    TextView age;
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<Employee> results = new ArrayList<Employee>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = employeeArrayList;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (final Employee g : orig) {
                        if (g.getName().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            employeeArrayList = (ArrayList<Employee>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return employeeArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return employeeArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    EmployeeHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        holder=new EmployeeHolder();
        holder.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.age=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder=(EmployeeHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(employeeArrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.age.setText(String.valueOf(employeeArrayList.get(position).getAge()));

    return convertView;

}}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
private SearchView mSearchView;
private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<Employee> employeeArrayList;
private EmployeeAdapter employeeAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSearchView=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
    mListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    employeeArrayList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
    employeeArrayList.add(new Employee("ABC", 24));
    employeeArrayList.add(new Employee("ACB", 24));
    employeeArrayList.add(new Employee("BVF", 28));
    employeeArrayList.add(new Employee("BRT", 28));
    employeeArrayList.add(new Employee("ANM", 23));

    employeeAdapter=new EmployeeAdapter(MainActivity.this, employeeArrayList);
    mListView.setAdapter(employeeAdapter);

    mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    setupSearchView();
    registerClickCallback();


}


private void registerClickCallback() {
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            Employee pick = employeeArrayList.get(position);

            String message = "You Selected " + pick.getName();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

private void setupSearchView()
{
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
{

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        mListView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        mListView.setFilterText(newText);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
{
    return false;
}}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `on the specified row that the user searched on the searchView`? you don't want a clickListener for all the rows?

Comment: I want a clickListener on all the rows. its just that when i search something on the searchview. and use the clickListener it always shows the first rows clicklistener instead of the one i searched.

Comment: Post your code (where you implement the clickListener).

Comment: @Rami i updated my post. i put the clickListener on mainactivity.java

Comment: So you mean your onItemClick is programmed to the list before it changed to display the search results .

Comment: As "TheAnimatrix" sayed, use  `employeeAdapter.getItem(position);` instead of `employeeArrayList.get(position);`

Answer (score -1):

Its simple ,

in your onItemClickListener(),  try using employeeadapter.getItem() instead of employeearraylist.get().

Try it and comment with the outcome . :D

Btw , your adapter is already loaded with the job of recycling the items . It's not a very good idea to put the filtering load on it too.

Just have the filtering happen inside of your activity and make it return an arraylist and just set your list adapter to this arraylist and call setOnItemClickListener() again to change an existing onItemClickListener().

Comment: `mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You selected "+employeeAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });` I put this and still doesnt work when i Click on it. it says error.

Comment: Could you send me a the classes and I will give you a proper sorted out one tomorrow , that is if you are willing to share..